# Surf all pages of a web link with curl

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl

i use :

```
curl http://www.alibaba.com/corporations/Electrical_Plugs_%2526_Sockets/CID13--CN------------------50--OR------------BIZ1,BIZ2/30.html | iconv -f windows-1251 | grep -o -h 'data' >>out
```

to filter data and save to `out` ,but the link got 67 pages ,how to surf all page of that link and save to `out` .

Thanks much for any help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with for loop

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

url="http://www.alibaba.com/corporations/Electrical_Plugs_%2526_Sockets/CID13--CN------------------50--OR------------BIZ1,BIZ2"

for i in {1..67}
do
   curl $url/${i}.html | iconv -f windows-1251 >> out.$i
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Httrack to download an entire website and then use command line tools to search for specific content locally

http://www.nightbluefruit.com/blog/2010/03/copying-an-entire-website-with-httrack/

Alternatively, you could use the -r recursive switch in wget

http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Recursive-Retrieval-Options.html

Comment: can you help me to config httrack ,i do know how to achieve my goal